# Why is an Aggregate function within an aggregate function different between oracle and mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have seen some information here on Stackoverflow and on other websites saying that an Aggregate within an Aggregate will not work in mysql.  I am taking a graduate course and was given a question:

a) What is the maximum number of pilots who can fly any aircraft?

Now, the professor provided a solution which was as follows:

```
SELECT MAX(COUNT(*))
FROM Certified
GROUP BY aid;

Result
MAX(COUNT(*))
-------------
6
```

He is covering this course using Oracle.  And I tried it in Oracle and it worked.

I tried this in mysql however and it did not work.  I ended up having to use a table subquery instead.  My query was:

```
SELECT MAX(canFly.numPilots)
FROM (SELECT aid, COUNT(*) as numPilots
    FROM certified
    GROUP BY aid) as canFly;

Result
Max(canFly.numPilots)
6
```

I don't have any issue personally with doing it this way and I think it makes more sense in my head doing it like this.

However, my question is why is this aggregate in an aggregate fine in Oracle but not fine in mySql?  Is there some reason for it being this way?

Comment: Most RDBMS's will not let you aggregate an aggregate without a subquery. In the case of a GROUP BY being present (since it's nonsense otherwise), Oracle is an exception.

Comment: @JNevill is there a particular reason that this is an exception in oracle?

Comment: It's just the way it is. Older versions of MySQL would allow you to leave non-aggregated fields out of a group by without throwing errors. Sql Server STILL doesn't have regex functionality. Teradata has a QUALIFY clause that no other RDBMS has. Oracle has a decode() function that is absent in many other RDBMS's. They each are different in their own ways. This double-aggregate functionality is a very handy feature. I wish it were implemented in more products.

Comment: You are asking why this Honda doesn't have a feature you have seen in that Ford. They are different products. They have a standard: both have four wheels, both have an engine, a steering wheel, etc. You are asking why you need a key to pop the trunk on the Honda, when on the Ford you can do it with your remote key. The "standard" in databases is the SQL Standard, which does NOT allow an aggregate within an aggregate. Oracle probably had their "thing" in their product *before* the Standard itself was written.

Comment: `I don't have any issue personally with doing it [the standard] way` great, do it that way in Oracle too: it is more "maintainable" than product specific shortcuts that aren't always understood by all coders.